# Math in CSS content property

Tags: css

Is there a way to do math in pure CSS and show the result in the `content` property? I try to do something like this, but it does not work.

```css
h1:before{
    --a: 2;
    --b: 3;
    --c: calc(var(--a) * var(--b));
    content: var(--c);
}
```